# Ubuntu OS on SSD and RAID-5 for data files

Tags: boot, mount, ssd, raid, nas

I want my NAS to run a lot like Freenas or Nas4free in that I have a separate drive for my OS and all other files (like WWW, media, plex media server and minecraft) run off the raid-5 (3*3tb WD reds).

Do I mount the root boot and swap on ssd and only home on raid5, or is there a better way of doing this. Maybe installing the whole OS on ssd then point over to the raid array?

Answer (score 0):

So you have four disks, one SSD that stands alone, and three 3TB drives in a RAID5 set. It sounds like you won't be doing much on your home directory, with your web, media, plex, etc. on the RAID array. So I would install the OS (root) and swap on the SSD and then mount the RAID device on a directory and carve it up into your requisite subdirectories. That way, you have the speed of the ssd for the OS, but you have the protection of RAID for the web, media, etc. files.

Comment: Yes 4 disk 3 in raid 5 and 1 ssd please elaborate on what u mean... Because it sounds like the same as what I posted. Root and swap on ssd and home on raid 5?

Answer (score 0):

Very short answer: **Yes!**

"/" and swap on SSD, "/home" (and any other files) on RAID-5